# Magento2.1 Category custom attribute dropdown

Tags: magento-2.1

### Steps to reproduce

**1. Module UpgradeData.php script contains:**

```
$categorySetup->addAttribute(Category::ENTITY, 'roflcopter', [
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'label' => 'CMS Block',
                    'input' => 'select',
                    'source' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Page',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 20,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'group' => 'Display Settings',
            ]);
```

**2. view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="Navigation">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Navigation</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="roflcopter">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Roflcopter</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

### Expected result

1. In category form should appear dropdown select Roflcopter with CMS Blocks as options

### Actual result

1. Empty dropdown

Comment: https://gielberkers.com/adding-custom-category-attributes-magento-2-1/#comment-3831

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add options tag for creating select options. In your case this should be

```
<field name="roflcopter">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Page</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Roflcopter</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: Maybe you know if i can show/hide this tab and/or its attributes based on some conditions, for example category depth?

Comment: THANKS! I was searching for this for so long. Docs are so unclear on this topic. How do you know this?

Comment: Data is not saved in database    @Sohel Rana

Answer (score 2):

I have done in my case. I have custom options ex. L1, L2 and L3. I need to get them on custom attribute as values. So I was created a source file in module - vendor\module\Model\Config\Source\Options.php

this file contain the small code to create the options, Here you can follow the code

```
 <?php
    /**
     * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    namespace Vendor\module\Model\Config\Source;
    /**
     * Catalog category landing page attribute source
     *
     * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
     */
    class Options extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         * @codeCoverageIgnore
         */
        public function getAllOptions()
        {
            if (!$this->_options) {
                $this->_options = [
                    ['value' => 'l1', 'label' => __('L1')],
                    ['value' => 'l2', 'label' => __('L2')],
                    ['value' => 'l3', 'label' => __('L3')],
                ];
            }
            return $this->_options;
        }
          /**
         * Get options in "key-value" format
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function toArray()
        {
            return [
                'l1' => __('L1'),
                'l2' => __('L2'),
                'L3' => __('L3'),
                ];
        }

    }
```

then after in your installdata.php you have to call this as source

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Category::ENTITY,
            'category_level_rendering',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Category Level rendering',
                'input' => 'select',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'source' => '',
                'visible'  => true,
                'source' => 'vendor\module\Model\Config\Source\Options',
                'default'  => '0',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
             ]
        );
```

Then also add the line in xml file

```
<field name="category_level_rendering">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
/*Here is the code added to get the options on dropdown*/
<item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\module\Model\Config\Source\Options</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Level Rendering</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
```

Save it, flush cache and please check.

> Hopefully it helps to you.
>
> Please give me reply if it works to you.

Comment: I got this kinds of error:

Element 'field': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( settings, column, actionsColumn, selectionsColumn ).
Line: 681

Comment: how did you save the data,

Comment: Data is not saved in database   @Jdprasad V

Comment: This is worked for me, kindly check again, if you did any changes on schema page.

Comment: Following to your code, it display admin side fine. But data is not saved in database table. I created successfully 4 attributes using your code. Now problem is toi save data into database. In eav_attribute table only one attribute saved in table. 3 attributes are not saved in table.

Comment: Let me check and update you on the status here. give me some time.

Comment: Thanks for looked and resolved the issue. Hopefully, it helps who needs to create attribute options programmatically. Thank you.