# How to call admin form field renderer in magento 2

Tags: backend, magento-2.1, renderer

Question is very clear. I want to display custom drop-down options which are collection of other custom module in admin form.

I did something like this after @Sohel Rana suggested [This question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123785/magento2-1-category-custom-attribute-dropdown).

**`form.xml` (From 1st module)**:

```
<field name="category">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <!-- Call to collection of 2nd module -->
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Namespace\Modulename\Block\Item\ItemList</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">mode</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">category</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

**ItemList.php (From 2nd module)**:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block\Item;


use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Namespace\Modulename\Model\Item;
use Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory as ItemCollectionFactory;
use Namespace\Modulename\Api\Data\ItemInterface;




class ItemList extends Template
{

    protected $itemCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ItemCollectionFactory $itemCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->itemCollectionFactory = $itemCollectionFactory;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }



    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = $this->itemCollectionFactory->create()->load()->toOptionArray();
            array_unshift($this->_options, ['value' => '', 'label' => __('Please select a category.')]);
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return $this->_toOptionArray('id', 'title');
    }

}
```

I am getting following error on form page of first module.

> Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given
>   in
>   /var/www/magento-2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Element/AbstractOptionsField.php
>   on line 54
>
> #1 /var/www/magento-2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Element/AbstractOptionsField.php(54):
>   array_values(Object(Namespace\Modulename\Block\Item\ItemList))

Comment: check this one. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123785/magento2-1-category-custom-attribute-dropdown

Comment: Hey @Sohel Rana i have updated my question and made changes as you suggested from above link. But i am stuck on this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't check this solution, but try to change:

```
class ItemList extends Template
```

to the:

```
class ItemList extends Template implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
```

Because in the **`\Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\AbstractOptionsField::prepare()`** method exists the check:

```
if ($this->options instanceof OptionSourceInterface) {
    $options = $this->options->toOptionArray();
} else {
    $options = array_values($this->options);
}
```

Make sure that the `_toOptionArray` method exists in your class `Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection` and it is a **`Public` method** (or use the `toOptionArray` method).

```
public function toOptionArray()
 {
      return $this->_toOptionArray('id', 'title');
 }
```

#### Complete code of your class:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block\Item;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Namespace\Modulename\Model\Item;
use Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory as ItemCollectionFactory;
use Namespace\Modulename\Api\Data\ItemInterface;

class ItemList extends Template implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
{

    protected $itemCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ItemCollectionFactory $itemCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->itemCollectionFactory = $itemCollectionFactory;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = $this->itemCollectionFactory
                ->create()
                ->load()
                ->toOptionArray('id', 'title');
            array_unshift($this->_options, ['value' => '', 'label' => __('Please select a category.')]);
        }

        return $this->_options;
    }

}
```

Comment: `Invalid method Namespace\Modulename\Block\Item\ItemList::_toOptionArray` should i add anything else?

Comment: @HungryDB see updated answer

Comment: Will you rewrite `getAllOptions` function for me (the one which i mentioned in question)? I don't understand how it will get call to `_toOptionArray()`.

Comment: @HungryDB I have made changes to your class and have added a code to the answer

Comment: Ok. the way i understand it, i have to call `toOptionArray()` public method in `Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection`. But then how does it will return an array of collection/options?

Comment: @HungryDB it is using the `\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection::_toOptionArray` method where the corresponding fields (from the input parameters) are transformed to the option array.

Comment: i will edit your answer to add `toOptionArray()` function which worked for me. Thanks for help.